# ViewData in _LoginPartial

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, viewdata

I have created ASP.NET Core application and now I'm trying to use ViewBag in _LoginPartial. I have created base controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public BaseController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        ViewData["MyKey"] = _db.MyTable.ToList();
    }
}
```

All my controllers derive from this BaseController.

But when I see ViewData in _LoginPartial.cshtml, I can only see that it contains default Key=Title, Value=Home Page. What should I do to have MyKey available in _LoginPartial?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not possible. Are you sure you are inheriting `BaseController`? What if you do this: `ViewData["MyKey"] = "Test Passes"`, does that work?

Comment: My controller is called BaseController. I inherit it from Controller. And all my controllers inherit from BaseController. When I set breakpoint in the view and hover mouse over ViewData in _LoginPartial, I don't see MyKey key, only Title key. When I try it with something as simple as you suggested (assigning string to the key), it's the same - I can't see it in the ViewData.

Comment: No that is not possible. Create another project and do the same test and you will see it 100%. It is some other issue.

Comment: I have created new project, as you suggested, and see the same issue. I create "BaseController : Controller" with constructor "public BaseController() { ViewData["MyKey"] = "Test Passes"; }". I remove Index() method from BaseController. Then I change HomeController so that it inherits from BaseController. And in _LoginPartial I write "<li>@ViewBag["MyKey"]</li>". I set breakpoint there and see in ViewData only {[Title, HomePage]}. I must be doing something wrong but I don't see what.

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out why this isn't working, you should simply throw it away entirely. This is an incredibly bad idea. You're creating tight coupling between your controllers and views (bad), querying a database in your controller constructor (bad), and not using async EF methods (bad... this code can and will deadlock). What you're looking for here is a view component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set `ViewData` content within the controller’s constructor.

The `ViewData` dictionary is not actually created by the controller. It is created at a very different point within the MVC pipeline and then gets *injected* into the controller. You can basically see this process as something like this:

```
// create controller
var controller = CreateController<MyController>();

// do stuff

// inject ViewData
controller.ViewData = GetViewDataDictionary();

// invoke controller action
var result = controller.SomeAction();
```

So the `ViewData` gets provided *after* the controller has been created; after its constructor ran. So any assignments to the view data *within* the constructor will not apply to the actual view data dictionary.

As such, you will need to set those values at a different time, you cannot use the constructor there. Using the `ViewData` in general is somewhat legacy construct that you should try to avoid if possible. Instead, you should work with strongly typed view model objects. Of course, this will require you to pass the data explicitly in each action, but that way you are also not introducing any implicit data flow.

An alternative, which is especially useful if what you are doing should actually always apply to the `_LoginPartial`, would be to use a view component. [View components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1) are reusable components that you can use inside of your views, which will behave similarly to a controller action. So you could just insert a view component into your partial, and have that run the logic (asynchronously even!) to provide the data from your database. And you wouldn’t need to mess with any of your controllers to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewData` can be accessed after controller has been activated or by overrinding `OnActionExecuting`.

> ```
>     //
>     // Summary:
>     //     Gets or sets Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary used by
>     //     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.ViewBag.
>     //
>     // Remarks:
>     //     By default, this property is intiailized when Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.IControllerActivator
>     //     activates controllers.
>     //     This property can be accessed after the controller has been activated, for example,
>     //     in a controller action or by overriding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.OnActionExecuting(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext).
>     //     This property can be also accessed from within a unit test where it is initialized
>     //     with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider.
>     [ViewDataDictionary]
>     public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
> ```

For a solution, you could try overring `OnActionExecuting` like below:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public BaseController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        ViewData["MyKey"] = _db.Product.ToList();
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

}
```

`_LoginPartial.cshtml`

```
@foreach (Product item in @ViewData["MyKey"] as IList<Product>)
{
    <li><a>@item.Name</a></li>
}
```